# Layout that calls data to activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a layout that can have static text and next to it text from the DB being called on different button clicks.

So i have 10 image button on 1 activity and when one is clicked a new activity starts and a list view appears.Once the user chooses there choice i would like a layout appears that will have static text i.e Beds,pets,Views.Then the information from the database that i call will be aside the text i.e 2 for beds,no pets, 4 star view. But i want to be able to use this layout on all Image buttons if can, its just the data changing on right that i need to change  and call.

I have looked about on the net but cant find what i need.

http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3797/ic5l.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have more than approx 10 of the static text + db text the you should be using a listview. You will need to write a custom list adapter that inflates a layout file like below. The reason you want a listview is because it recycles views for efficiency.

For the inflated listitem xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    ..etc >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewStatic"
        android:text="text you set statically later for each item">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewDb"
        android:text="text you set vis db later for each item">
    </TextView>
<LinearLayout>
```

If you only have a few of the text items just inflate the layout and add it to another layout.

```
<LinearLayout        
    ..etc >
    <ImageView>
        image properties
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/mTextLayout"
         properties..>

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Then you can add it manually outside a listview by:

```
LinearLayout mTextLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.mTextLayout);
//add multiple instances of the "listItem" xml
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    LinearLayout listItem = inflater.inflate(theListItemAbove);
    TextView tvStatic = listItem.findViewById(R.id.mTextViewStatic);
    tvStatic.setText("my static text");
    TextView tvDb = listItem.findViewById(R.id.mTextViewDb);
    tvStatic.setText(db.getStuff());
    mTextLayout.addView(listItem);
}
```